# If game is closed, open pauseLayer (cocos2d iPhone development)

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, multitasking, layer

How do I incorporate into my AppDelegate that if a user is on a Level and exits the game (pressed home button), then the next time it's opened (multitasking) it will open the pauseLayer? I don't want the game to immediately start after they have switched back to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In detail:

```
-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application {
if(gameisRunning)
{
[self pauseLayer];
}
}
```

=)

Comment: How do I program gameIsRunning?

Comment: create a singleton.. something like sharedData.. So when game is running, set sharedData.gameisRunning to true.. When not running, set sharedData.gameisRunning to false..

Comment: Ok, but what _is_ gameIsRunning?

Comment: gameisRunning is a condition to check if your game is running or not.. if you are in game, set gameisRunning to true in your init.. When the game is quit, set the gameisRunning to false..

Comment: Hmmm.. Do you know how singleton works?? Or even create a singleton?

Comment: I'm not exactly familar with the term, maybe I'll recognize it after researching it up a bit

Comment: Does  this (http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/30/the-objective-c-singleton/) look like a good place to learn about singletons? I'm guessing I put the true/false things in the init of the gameIsRunning singleton?

Comment: Quick question - If I was going to need to use multiple singletons (not referring to this situation) would I need to create a new class for it? Could I just make it inherit from my original singleton class? So that I could acheive the effect in the .h - MySecondSingleton : Singleton ? How can I do that? I'm thinking that I will need to use 3-4 singletons in total in my game, so I don't want to make an entirely new class for each one.

Comment: Now I am further confused. Is sharedData the singleton, or is gameIsRunning? And what is the other?

Comment: sharedData is a singleton.. gameIsRunning is a member of the sharedData singleton.. can email me at junxron@gmail.com? i can attach some sample codes for you to make you understand..

Comment: I haven't gone through the source code you've sent me, but I accepted your answer. Thanks for your help! I'll send you a reply email if I have any troubles.

Answer (score 1):

inside applicationDidEnterBackground, add a line of code to check whether the game is running. if the game is running, open the pauseLayer. this way when the player open it from multitasking the game will be paused.

Comment: How do I check if the game is running?